# Portable applications Benchmark/speed

Tags: windows-7, windows, portable, portable-harddrive

I am setting up a new PC and I was thinking of getting as many programs/applications as portables (so I can keep the PC "cleaner"). My main concern is, does portable make the application run "slower" or are there any disadvantages compared to a "full" installation?

Comment: Assuming a program can be made portable (some can't), it may run slower or faster depending on how it's coded, but since you'll be running it from your local hard disk I bet you'll never notice any difference. File associations aren't possible if you want to maintain strict portability, in the sense that the program should write as little as possible (or not at all) to the registry. However since you're not going to run them from a USB drive, you can set up file associations just as with installed apps.